# Angular ng-bind only binds once

Tags: angularjs

The browser console shows $scope.counter incrementing but why doesn't the page increment?

It shows "**counter=100**" so I know the bind worked once, but not (101, 102, ...) subsequent times as the timer fires:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="bindInterval">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('bindInterval', [])
      .controller('bindIntervalController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.counter = 100;
        window.setInterval(function() {
          $scope.counter += 1;
          console.log($scope.counter);
        }, 1000);
      }]);
  </script>
</head>
<body><div ng-controller="bindIntervalController">counter={{counter}}</div></body>
</html>
```

Code at [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ob6Wh9PnbcL6KtPUXy0L)

I've Googled this but they only show {{::name}} which is different.

Comment: Also stuck at 100: <span ng-bind="counter"></span>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `setInterval` doesnt trigger a digest cycle. You need to use the `$interval` module provided by Angular:

```
angular.module('bindInterval', [])
  .controller('bindIntervalController', ['$scope', '$interval' function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.counter = 100;
    $interval(function() {
      $scope.counter += 1;
      console.log($scope.counter);
    }, 1000);
  }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `setInterval` in angularjs because angular would not see the changes that way. use `$interval` instead.